# libGDX: convert TextureRegion to Texture

Tags: libgdx, textures, texturepacker

How can I use my dragon as a Texture?

```
atlas = new TextureAtlas("myPack.atlas"); 
dragon = dragon.findRegion("dragon"); // returns TextureRegion
```

Comment: `atlas.findRegion("dragon");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating `Texture` from `TextureRegion` is totally pointless.

---

Your `TextureRegion` having rectangular points of your Texture so you can write particular texel to pixmap and then create `Texture` from that `Pixmap`.

```
TextureAtlas.TextureAtlasData.Region dragon = atlas.getRegion("dragon");
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(dragon.width, dragon.height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
FileHandle pngFile = dragon.page.textureFile;

Pixmap completePix = new Pixmap(pngFile);
pixmap.drawPixmap(completePix, 0, 0, dragon.left, dragon.top, dragon.width, dragon.height);

Texture dragonTex=new Texture(pixmap);
```